# ExtJS Model - Concatenate fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a sensible way in a model to concatenate two fields, something like this:

```
Ext.define('model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'Id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'FullName', type: 'string', mapping: 'FirstName + " " + LastName' }
    ]
});
```

I've tried a multitude of ways, but can't seem to get any to work.

I was going to use a function in the model to stick the two fields together, but I also need to use this as the displayfield inside a 'itemselector' (custom control) and switch this dynamically and that control doesn't seem to like 'FullName()' as a displayfield.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `convert` config of the Ext.data.Field: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert

```
{ name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
{ name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
{
    name: 'FullName',
    type: 'string',
    convert: function( v, record ) {
       return record.get( 'FirstName' ) + ' ' + record.get( 'LastName' )
    }
}
```

Here's a live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mf

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately i notice it appends the new property when making a request to the store, so the compound value comes down the wire which is what I was trying to avoid, either way, great answer.

Comment: To prevent that field from being submitted as a part of the request, simply add persist: false to the field definition.

Comment: Correction: the converted fields weren't coming down the wire I hadn't updated my server side code!